# If $x+y+z+w=29$ where x, y and z are real numbers greater than 2, then find the maximum possible value of $(x-1)(y+3)(z-1)(w-2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

> If $x+y+z+w=29$ where x, y and z are real numbers greater than 2, then find the maximum possible value of $(x-1)(y+3)(z-1)(w-2)$.

$(x-1)+(y+3)+(z-1)+(w-2)=x+y+z+w-1=28$

Now $x-1=y+3=z-1=w-2=7$ since product is maximum when numbers are equal

My answer came out to be as $6*10*6*5=1800$ but the answer is $2401$. What am I doing wrong? And also, how we will get the answer $2401$

Comment: is $w$ also greater than $2$

Comment: WHat? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: the Maximum is given by $2401$ for $x=8,y=4,z=8,w=9$

Comment: Try Lagrange multipliers

Comment: i want to know if $w$ also grater than $2$ is?

Comment: Nothing like that is given as such in question @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: i think the searched Minimum is zero

Comment: I am curious why you chose to accept an answer that is rated down twice, I showed all the work necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: The component parts of your product are all $7$ and $7^4=49^2=2401$ - you are not supposed to be computing $wxyz$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$x=8, y=4, z=8, w=9$  is the solution.

edit:
your solution is also correct. I don't know why are you multiplying $6∗10∗6∗5$?

$x−1=y+3=z−1=w−2=7$  means 7*7*7*7=2401

Comment: Why I can't assume them as equal. Product is maximum only when numbers are equal @James

Comment: I calculated them on paper.

Comment: How did you get that? @James Also, my teacher taught me that product is maximum only when numbers are equal

Comment: yes your solution is also correct  7, 7,7,7 is also correct what is your mistake is that you multiplied x*y*z*w  instead of   (x−1)(y+3)(z−1)(w−2).

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x,y,z,w) = (x-1)(y+3)(z-1)(w-2)$$ and $$g(x,y,z,w) = x + y + w - 29$$
We want to $$\max\{f(x,y,x,w)\}$$ 
subject to:
$$g(x,y,z,w) = 0, \ \ \ x,y,z > 2$$
Let
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) &= f(x,y,z,w) + \lambda g(x,y,z,w)\\ &= (x-1)(y+3)(z-1)(w-2) + \lambda(x + y + w - 29)
\end{align*}
Then 
$$\nabla \mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) = 0$$ yields $4$ equations:

\begin{equation}{\tag{1}}
(y+3)(z-1)(w-2) + \lambda = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{2}}
(x-1)(z-1)(w-2) + \lambda = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{3}}
(x-1)(y+3)(w-2) + \lambda = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{4}}
(x-1)(y+3)(z-1) + \lambda = 0
\end{equation}

Now when you set each one equal to each other and find another four equations where $y$ will be a linear combination of $x,y,w$ we find another $4$ equations:

\begin{equation}{\tag{5}}
y = x - 4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{6}}
y = z - 4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{7}}
y = y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}{\tag{8}}
y = w - 5
\end{equation}

Now, we see that 
$$(y+4) + y + (y + 4) + (y+5) = 29 \Rightarrow y = 4$$

Then it is trivial to find $x,z,w$ by plugging in $y=4$ to the equations above. Hope that helps!

Comment: You should get $x = 8,z = 8$ and $w = 9$.  Then just plug into $f(x,y,z,w)$ and you are done.